# Backbone validation plugin does not validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, backbone.js

I am using [Backbone.Validation](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation) plugin to validate a simple form. Below is my model

```
var BuyerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        age: ''
    },

    validation: {
        name: {
            required: true
        },
        age: { 
            min: 18
        }
    },

    initialize: function () {
        _.extend(Backbone.Model.prototype, Backbone.Validation.mixin);
    }

});
```

Below is my view

```
var BuyerModelFormView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        'click [name~="save"]': 'save'
    },

    initialize: function () {
        Backbone.Validation.bind(this);
    },

    template: _.template('\
         <form>\
               Enter name:\
               <input name="name" type="text" value="<%= name %>"><br>\
               Enter age:\
               <input name="age" type="text" value="<%= age %>"><br>\
               <input type="button" name="save" value="Save">\
        </form>\ '),

    render: function () {
        var html = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
        $(this.el).html(html);
    },

    save: function () {
        console.log(this.model.toJSON());
        this.model.set({
            name: $('[name~="name"]').val(),
            age: $('[name~="age"]').val()
        });

        console.log(this.model.toJSON());
    }

});
```

Here is how I am using it

```
    var buyerModel = new BuyerModel();

    var buyerModelFormView = new BuyerModelFormView({
        model: buyerModel,
        el: 'body'
    });

    buyerModelFormView.render();
```

When I enter anything in the form and hit enter it updates model but does not validate. Even if I enter incorrect value model still gets update.

**What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set force validation like this

```
this.model.set({
    name: $('[name~="name"]').val(),
    age: $('[name~="age"]').val()
}, {validate: true});
```

Is it what you want?

Because Model.set has such string

```
// Run validation.
      if (!this._validate(attrs, options)) return false;
```

And

```
// Run validation against the next complete set of model attributes,
// returning `true` if all is well. Otherwise, fire an `"invalid"` event.
_validate: function(attrs, options) {
  if (!options.validate || !this.validate) return true;
```

So if you didn't pass validate - it will be ignored

Check in such way

```
$(function(){
    var buyerModel = new BuyerModel();

    buyerModel.on('change', function(){
        console.log('on change', arguments);
    });

    var buyerModelFormView = new BuyerModelFormView({
        model: buyerModel,
        el: 'body'
    });

    buyerModelFormView.render();
});
```

Comment: It does now validate but it still updates model even with incorrect values.

Comment: No, it don't - model has empty valuers from defaults section

Comment: A've add age 23 - it works ok. Can you show your code at jsbin? I check on latests version of libs and http://jsbin.com/kiyayunuzo/1/edit?js,output